# Tryton: How can I Make One2Many field view using more space in view

Tags: tryton

I have my form view defined as follow in the tryton client

```
<form>
    <group id="form">
         <label name="capo_famiglia" />
         <field name="capo_famiglia"/>         
         <label name="tipo_famiglia" />
         <field name="tipo_famiglia"/>
         <label name="data_inizio" />
         <field name="data_inizio" widget="date"/>         
         <label name="data_fine" />
         <field name="data_fine" widget="date"/>
        <field name="componenti"
               colspan="4" 
               view_ids="registry.family_date_view_tree,registry.family_date_view_form"/>
    </group>
</form>
```

the field **componenti** is a **One2Many** fields.

the widget show me only 2 records in the form view, even if I put 3 or 4 records.

I try to make as done in sale_order,using notebook, and yexpand but without any result.

This is the view:

[Click To View the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTNB4.png)

any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I guess your are using the web client. Because with the desktop client One2Many widget fill all the available vertical space. This behavior could not be mimicked on the web so the best solution found for now is a default min-height=100px and max-height=300px. Normally it is should be enough to show 8 rows.

Comment: Dear Ced, I just update the question, we are using tryton not sao

Comment: In this case, I guess it is because group are not expanded by default. So you must add yexpand="1" to the group.
But it is not necessary to use a group to contain the all form.

Comment: thanks for the replay, I remove the group as you suggest and it work like a charm, regards